# Google Domains DDNS with DDclient on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dns, ddclient

Evening everyone,
I asked the same question on [stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849353/google-domains-ddns-with-ddclient-on-ubuntu) however it has been a several days and almost no views and no hints.
I am using ddclient to update google domains with my ip.  However I am always getting the error:

```
WARNING:  skipping update of @ from <nothing> to 73.102.13.168.
WARNING:   last updated <never> but last attempt on Wed Jun 15 07:49:22 2016 failed.
WARNING:   Wait at least 5 minutes between update attempts.
```

I have tried several different configurations but I am at a loss of why I would keep getting these every time I try to run the update.  I am behind a router but am using checkip.dyndns.com and it is correctly getting my dynamic IP address.  Here is my config file as it stands now.  Happy to provide any other info.

Thanks for and greatly appreciate any help even if it is pointing me to a starting point!!

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

daemon=600
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid

protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com, web-skip='Current IP Address: '
server=domains.google.com
login=****
password='****'
sub, sub.here.com

protocol=dyndns2
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.com, web-skip='Current IP Address: '
server=domains.google.com
login=****
password='****'
@, here.com
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: I did get it fixed.  I will post the fix either tonight or tomorrow when I get home.  I don't remember what the issue was off the top of my head

Comment: @Bulsatar it's been 5 years. I hope you made it home safely. :D